# OSDEV. Why does my int 0x80 cause a General Protection fault?

Tags: exception, x86, interrupt, qemu, osdev

I am learning to use *gcc, nasm, and qemu* to develop a toy OS on *i386*.
And I tried to initialize the *IDT* and added some *interrupt handlers*. But I got a strange error I can't understand.

Here is the [github repo](https://github.com/kunikloj/minios/). Following are some details about the problem.

I think the problem is hidden in the **main.c**.

```
#define IDT_ADDR 0x2000
#define AR_INTGATE32 0x8e

typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short int uint16_t;
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;

//remapping pic
#define PIC0_ICW1 0x20
#define PIC0_OCW2 0x20
#define PIC0_IMR  0x21
#define PIC0_ICW2 0x21
#define PIC0_ICW3 0x21
#define PIC0_ICW4 0x21
#define PIC1_ICW1 0xa0
#define PIC1_OCW2 0xa0
#define PIC1_IMR  0xa1
#define PIC1_ICW2 0xa1
#define PIC1_ICW3 0xa1
#define PIC1_ICW4 0xa1

static inline void outb(uint16_t port, uint8_t val) {
    asm volatile ( "outb %0, %1" : : "a"(val), "Nd"(port) );
}

void init_pic() {
    outb(PIC0_IMR, 0xff);
    outb(PIC1_IMR, 0xff);
    outb(PIC0_ICW1, 0x11);
    outb(PIC0_ICW2, 0x20);   /* IRQ0-7 -> INT 0x20-0x27*/
    outb(PIC0_ICW3, 1<<2);
    outb(PIC0_ICW4, 0x01);
    outb(PIC1_ICW1, 0x11);
    outb(PIC1_ICW2, 0x28);   /* IRQ8-15 -> INT 0x28-0x2f */
    outb(PIC1_ICW3, 2);
    outb(PIC1_ICW4, 0x01);
    outb(PIC0_IMR, 0xfc);    /* 11111011 PIC1*/
    outb(PIC1_IMR, 0xff);
}

struct idt_entry_t {
    uint16_t    isr_low;      // The lower 16 bits of the ISR's address
    uint16_t    kernel_cs;    // The GDT segment selector that the CPU will load into CS before calling the ISR
    uint8_t     reserved;     // Set to zero
    uint8_t     attributes;   // Type and attributes; see the IDT page
    uint16_t    isr_high;     // The higher 16 bits of the ISR's address
} __attribute__((packed));

void set_intrdesc(struct idt_entry_t *id, void* isr, uint16_t cs, uint8_t attr) {
    id->isr_low = (uint32_t)isr & 0xffff;
    id->kernel_cs = cs;
    id->reserved = 0;
    id->attributes = attr;
    id->isr_high = (uint32_t)isr >> 16;
}

struct idt_entry_t *idt = (struct idt_entry_t*)IDT_ADDR;

struct interrupt_frame {
    uint32_t tf_eip;
    uint16_t tf_cs;
    uint16_t tf_padding4;
    uint32_t tf_eflags;
};

__attribute__ ((interrupt))
void interrupt_handler_0x80(struct interrupt_frame *frame) {
    asm("mov $0x20, %eax");
    while (1);
}

__attribute__ ((interrupt))
void general_protection_handler13(struct interrupt_frame *frame, uint32_t error_code) {
    asm("mov $13, %eax");
    while (1);
}

#define KERNEL_CS 0x8

void init_idt() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        set_intrdesc(idt + i, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    set_intrdesc(idt + 13, general_protection_handler13, KERNEL_CS, AR_INTGATE32);
    
    struct {uint16_t limit; uint32_t addr;} __attribute__((packed)) idtr;
    idtr.limit = 255;
    idtr.addr = idt;
    asm volatile ("lidt %0" :: "m" (idtr));
}

void main() {
    init_idt();
    init_pic();

    asm("sti");
    
    set_intrdesc(idt + 0x80, interrupt_handler_0x80, KERNEL_CS, AR_INTGATE32);
    asm("int $0x80");

    while (1) {
        asm("hlt");
    }
}
```

When I try `make log "TERMINAL=xfce4-terminal"`

```
The result of make log "TERMINAL=xfce4-terminal" -- just-print

nasm boot.s -o boot.bin
nasm setup.s -o setup.bin
gcc main.c -O -march=i386 -m32 -g -fno-builtin -fno-PIC -Wall -nostdinc -fno-stack-protector -ffreestanding -ffunction-sections -mgeneral-regs-only -c -o main.o
ld -nostdlib -Tmain.ld main.o -o main.bin.elf
objdump -S main.bin.elf > main.bin.asm
objcopy -S -O binary main.bin.elf main.bin
dd if=/dev/zero of=test.img count=100
dd if=boot.bin of=test.img conv=notrunc
dd if=setup.bin of=test.img seek=1 conv=notrunc
dd if=main.bin of=test.img seek=2 conv=notrunc
qemu-system-i386 -no-reboot -S -s -d int  -D q.log -parallel stdio -hda test.img -serial null &
sleep 2
xfce4-terminal -e "gdb -q -x gdbinit"
```

, after `int $0x80`, the `gdb` will stop at `general_protection_handler13`.

Here are the `interrupt frame` and `error code` about the exception (I use a gdb plugin called gef).

```
Breakpoint 1, general_protection_handler13 (frame=0xefff4, error_code=0x402) at main.c:74
74      asm("mov $13, %eax");
gef➤  p *frame
$1 = {
  tf_eip = 0x823d, 
  tf_cs = 0x8, 
  tf_padding4 = 0x0, 
  tf_eflags = 0x247
}
gef➤  x/i 0x823d
   0x823d <main+61>:    int    0x80
gef➤  python print(bin(0x402), bin(0x80))
0b10000000010 0b10000000
```

Then I know the GPE was caused by `int $0x80` and the selector index in the error_code was correct.

The IDT entry of the GPE and the 0x80 are:

```
gef➤  p idt[13]
$2 = {
  isr_low = 0x8249, 
  kernel_cs = 0x8, 
  reserved = 0x0, 
  attributes = 0x8e, 
  isr_high = 0x0
}
gef➤  p idt[0x80]
$3 = {
  isr_low = 0x8242, 
  kernel_cs = 0x8, 
  reserved = 0x0, 
  attributes = 0x8e, 
  isr_high = 0x0
}
```

And here is the qemu's log about the interrupts.

```
     0: v=80 e=0000 i=1 cpl=0 IP=0008:0000823d pc=0000823d SP=0010:000f0000 env->regs[R_EAX]=00002000
EAX=00002000 EBX=00000000 ECX=00000001 EDX=00000000
ESI=00000000 EDI=00000000 EBP=000e0000 ESP=000f0000
EIP=0000823d EFL=00000247 [---Z-PC] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     0000802c 00000017
IDT=     00002000 000000ff
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000 
DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
CCS=00000001 CCD=00000000 CCO=SARL    
EFER=0000000000000000

check_exception old: 0xffffffff new 0xd
     1: v=0d e=0402 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:0000823d pc=0000823d SP=0010:000f0000 env->regs[R_EAX]=00002000
EAX=00002000 EBX=00000000 ECX=00000001 EDX=00000000
ESI=00000000 EDI=00000000 EBP=000e0000 ESP=000f0000
EIP=0000823d EFL=00000247 [---Z-PC] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     0000802c 00000017
IDT=     00002000 000000ff
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000 
DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
CCS=00000001 CCD=00000000 CCO=SARL    
EFER=0000000000000000
```

I think my GDT and IDT are correct.

I have read many answers about similar problems  in various websites but couldn't understand why my `int $0x80` will cause the `General Prorection Exception` and how to fix it.

Sorry for my stupid, but I really need some other people's help.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you very much!!! Just as expected it's a stupid problem, can't believe I didn't notice it...... QAQ. I must be too tired these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IDT=00002000 000000ff` suggests that your IDT is 0xff bytes in size (+1) or 256. But each IDT entry is 8 bytes. Maybe you meant to set size to 256*8-1 or 2047 (0x7ff). So it doesn't appear to me that the size is correct and 0x80 exception is beyond the limits of the IDT causing the #GP fault.

I noticed the code for this was in the question: `idtr.limit = 255;` should be `idtr.limit = 256*sizeof(idt_entry_t)-1;` .I'd also question why you chose to put the IDT at address 0x2000 and just didn't define an array of 256 `idt_entry_t` entries in *C* like `struct idt_entry_t idt[256];` and then just modify the code to use `IDT` as an array. You could then set the IDT limit with `sizeof(idt)-1`.

`SP=0010:000f0000` looks suspicious. *CR0* says paging is off. Physical address 0xf0000 is in the ROM BIOS memory area. Maybe set the stack *ESP* to 0x90000.